# Is it a bad practice to set default font-size on the html/body element?

Tags: css, font-size, typography

I want to have scalable font sizes but I don't know where to start. Is it a bad practice to set default font-size on the html/body element and to override the browser one? Does setting font size on the html/body create any issues with zooming? What should I use rems or pixels?

Comment: U can use percentage. Ex: font-size: 100%;

Comment: Usability-wise, it tends to be best to use relative sizes so that the user can continue to resize the text themselves using their browsers. However, I tend to use percentages to set a global font-size in my `html/body` attribute, and then from then on use `ems`.

Answer (score 3):

Can't answer for everybody, but if you want to set up a responsive web site, I suggest that you set the font in pixels, ex. 16px, and then use rem everywhere else, even for headlines.

This means that you could easily change (decrease) the font size on all places, through web queries, if the user is on a phone.

Different browsers zoom in different ways, but I never experienced any downside doing what I do.